# Using Jest to test node.js code, how do you test for the absence of a property

Tags: node.js, jestjs

What matcher would I use in [Jest](https://jestjs.io/en/) to test for the absence of a property on an object.

My MUT returns an object, say `{userName: 'Joe'}`.

How do I test that the object does **NOT** contain a property named `password`?

Such that this result would fail the test: `{userName: 'Joe', password: 'pwd'}`.

I've thought of `.toBeUndefined()`, but if the password property is there, and just contains an `undefined` value, the test would yield a false pass - such a case should fail, because the `password` property is there (even though it's value is `undefined`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `toHaveProperty` ?

```
const obj = { userName: 'Joe', password: 'pwd' };

it('obj should not have password property', () => {
 expect(obj).not.toHaveProperty('password');
});
```

Comment: uhg duh I can't believe I missed that one in the docs!!!  *stares blindly*!!!